# How do I target IE9 and above with grunt autoprefixer?

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, autoprefixer

How do I target IE9 and above with grunt autoprefixer? Can I do something like the following:

```
  grunt.config('autoprefixer', {
    options: {
      browsers: ['IE9+']
    },
    dist: {
      expand: true,
      src: '/styles/app.css'
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax for the `browsers` option can be found in the main [Autoprefixer documentation](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer#browsers). The relevant bits are:

> - `Firefox >= 20` is Firefox version 20 or newer.

And:

> Browsers names (case insensitive):
>
> - ...
> - `Explorer` or `ie` for Internet Explorer.

Hence, in order to target IE9 and newer, use:

```
options: {
  browsers: ['ie >= 9']
},
```